# TFS 2010 - how can external users access and internal TFS server

Tags: tfs

My organisation has setup a TFS 2010 server on its own internal network.  Us internal guys can push source code into it.  However we have a few external users who are not part of the network.  How can we get them to push source code to TFS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either expose your tfs server to the internet or (more common) have your external guys VPN to the internal network .